# How to replace value of Pandas column based on value in other column

Tags: python, pandas

Assume the following Pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
        'id' : [1, 2, 3, 4],
        'name' : ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz', 'Buzz'],
        'symbol' : ['F', '.', 'Mx2', 'M']
       }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df

    id  name    symbol
0   1   Foo     F
1   2   Bar     .
2   3   Baz     Mx2
3   4   Buzz    M
```

I'd like to be able to change the value in the `symbol` column based on the following conditions:

1. if `name` equals `Bar` and symbol equals `.`, then symbol is `F`
2. if `name` equals `Baz` and symbol equals `Mx2`, then symbol is `M`

The desired dataframe would look like this:

```
    id  name    symbol
0   1   Foo     F
1   2   Bar     F
2   3   Baz     M
3   4   Buzz    M
```

How would I implement this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.loc[]` for this:

```
df.loc[df.name.eq('Bar') & df.symbol.eq('.'), 'symbol'] = 'F'
df.loc[df.name.eq('Baz') & df.symbol.eq('Mx2'), 'symbol'] = 'M'
```

Output:

```
   id  name symbol
0   1   Foo      F
1   2   Bar      F
2   3   Baz      M
3   4  Buzz      M
```